# HTTPS redirect only working for base/root URL

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, https

I have the following set up for my virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} Off
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine if I visit `http://www.example.com` or `http://example.com`. However, if I go to a specific URL like `http://www.example.com/docs/` it does not redirect to HTTPS, and will maintain the non-secure connection. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to solve what's wrong with the `RewriteRule` this is a text book case of [When not to use mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect):

> To redirect http URLs to https, do the following:
>
> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     ServerName www.example.com 
>     Redirect "/" "https://www.example.com/"   
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

Just add the `ServerAlias`. It's also better to redirect to a *canonical* name.

Comment: Excellent! This usage of `RewriteRule` was automatically generated by `letsencrypt` when I configured the SSL certificate. But this works perfectly and is much cleaner!